# Recursive function that returns all values in list (In OCaml)

Tags: ocaml

I need a function that recursively returns (not prints) all values in a list with each iteration. However, every time I try programming this my function returns a list instead.

```
let rec elements list = match list with
 | [] -> []
 | h::t -> h; elements t;;
```

I need to use each element each time it is returned in another function that I wrote, so I need these elements one at a time, but I can't figure this part out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is equivalent to :

```
let rec elements list = 
  match list with 
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> elements t
```

This happens because `a ; b` evaluates `a` (and discards the result) and then evaluates and returns `b`. Obviously, this is in turn equivalent to:

```
let elements (list : 'a list) = []
```

This is not a very useful function.

Before you try solving this, however, please understand that **Objective Caml functions can only return one value**. Returning more than one value is impossible.

There are ways to work around this limitation. One solution is to pack all the values you wish to return into a single value: a tuple or a list, usually. So, if you need to return an arbitrary number of elements, you would pack them together into a list and have the calling code process that list:

```
let my_function () = [ 1 ; 2; 3; 4 ] in (* Return four values *)
List.iter print_int (my_function ())    (* Print four values *)
```

Another less frequent solution is to provide a function and call it on every result:

```
let my_function action = 
  action 1 ;
  action 2 ;
  action 3 ;
  action 4
in
my_function print_int
```

This is less flexible, but arguably faster, than returning a list : lists can be filtered, sorted, stored...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been thinking about doing this in two steps with two functions, like you described, but my problem is with retrieving each element one by one. I should be a little bit more specific. My main function is a subset function in which I am given the task of determining whether list a is a subset of list b. I am required to write this function in a way that is polymorphic, but right now I can only figure out how to do it with a list of ints.

Comment: The problem is because I wrote a function to return the first element of the list: let head list = match list with h::t -> h | [] -> 0. Since I have to account for the empty list, I return 0, and OCaml determines that this function takes a list of ints.  Since the subset function needs to be polymorphic, I cannot know ahead of time what to return for the empty set, be it 0, "null", or whatever. This therefore limits me to lists of ints.

Comment: in this case (what to return for the empty list), simply raise an error : (failwith "error")

Comment: I think you're going completely in the wrong direction on this matter. If you have trouble writing a subset function, I would advise you to ask a question about that - you would get answers that are cleaner and more adapted to your actual problem (such as `let subset a b = List.for_all (fun i -> List.mem i b) a`) as well as constructive comments on the code you already wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of confusing - you want a function that returns all the values in a list.  Well the easiest way of returning a variable number of values is using a list!  Are you perhaps trying to emulate Python generators?  OCaml doesn't have anything similar to `yield`, but instead usually accomplishes the same by "passing" a function to the value (using `iter`, `fold` or `map`).

What you have currently written is equivalent to this in Python:

```
def elements(list):
    if(len(list) == 0):
        return []
    else:
        list[0]
        return elements(list[1:])
```

If you are trying to do this:

```
def elements(list):
    if(len(list) > 0):
        yield list[0]
        # this part is pretty silly but elements returns a generator
        for e in elements(list[1:]):
            yield e

for x in elements([1,2,3,4,5]):
    dosomething(x)
```

The equivalent in OCaml would be like this:

```
List.iter dosomething [1;2;3;4;5]
```

If you are trying to determine if list a is a subset of list b (as I've gathered from your comments), then you can take advantage of `List.mem` and `List.for_all`:

```
List.for_all (fun x -> List.mem x b) a
```

`fun x -> List.mem x b` defines a function that returns true if the value x is equal to any element in (is a member of) b.  `List.for_all` takes a function that returns a bool (in our case, the membership function we just defined) and a list.  It applies that function to each element in the list.  If that function returns true for every value in the list, then `for_all` returns true.

So what we have done is: for all elements in a, check if they are a member of b.  If you are interested in how to write these functions yourself, then I suggest reading the source of list.ml, which (assuming *nix) is probably located in /usr/local/lib/ocaml or /usr/lib/ocaml.